# Преобразовать из std::string в uintptr_t

Tags: c++, преобразование

Я скачиваю строку сайта в переменную std::string, после чего хочу сделать из этой переменной указатель данных uintptr_t. Это представляется возможным? Я не могу понять, как мне вообще такое реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы из строки вытащить значение указателя, надо сделать следующее:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::string txt = "0xDEAD";
    uintptr_t x = strtoul(txt.c_str(), 0, 16);
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/rdNpyi)

Comment: Спасибо, но, по-моему, это немного не то, что мне нужно. Или я имею неправильное представление? Пример того, как должно быть: 
`std::string S = "0x117CC"
auto uPtr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t*>(mystr.data());
std::cout << uPtr;` 
//  Хочу вывод тот же, что и строка(0x117CC), но выводятся рандомные значения. Я новичок, поэтому ничего не могу понять. Хотелось бы объяснения

Comment: Так вам надо из строки вытащить шестнадцатиричное значение 0x117CC?

Comment: Видимо, я сначала неправильно написал. Да, мне нужно это значение вытащить из строки